# Travelling from Phuket,Thailand to Malaysia with Visa

Tags: visas, thailand, malaysia, solo-travel, phuket

I am planning to visit Thailand and Malaysia in November 2017.
I'm from India, and have a passport.

I know Thailand provides visas on arrival but Malaysia doesn't. 
So I am planning to get visa for both Thailand and Malaysia before travelling.

Details of trip: I am planning to reach Bangkok, from there Pattaya, then from there a long journey to Phuket.
From Phuket, I plan to leave Thailand by road, across the Malaysian border, so I would need to have my Malaysian visum there.
The trip is from the 2nd week till the end of November.

Can the visa for the two different countries overlap? E.g. can I have 2 visas for same duration, so that I would be free to visit anytime from Thailand,
instead of being stuck for a specific date.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, visa to different countries can definitely overlap. Myself I have a 10 year Indian and 10 year Chinese valid visas, which obviously overlap.

No obvious troubles with the chosen route either.

Comment: I once went to Thailand for 5 days, got a 30 day visa exemption stamp, then went to Cambodia for a week, got a visa on arrival, and then to Malaysia for a few days, got a visa on arrival. All of these had overlapping periods.
Oh, and I also had my Swiss work visa for years.

Comment: Could you also tell me , can i get a visa 3 months in advance? Like , i am travelling in November, can i apply now and get it for that time?